# Video Game on C++ with MFC visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, mfc

I don't know if I had gotten it all wrong, so I'm asking for directions here.

Let's take for example, back in college, when you learned C++ and used Turbo C++ or GCC to compile, you get an idea of what a low level programming language is.

Now let's say I want to make a basic 2D video game, just as a personal project, nothing fancy, and I want to develop it using C++ just because. I'd code it using Visual Studio since it's a pretty good IDE.

Is it right to say "I'm going to use MFC" for this kind of project? (Consider the fact that I'd be using OpenGL).

Comment: I'm not sure it has any moral implications so that "right" vs. "wrong" would really apply, but I think there would be barely short of universal agreement that few would even consider developing new code using MFC any more. For only one possible alternative, you might consider Qt instead.

Comment: Qt is lacking in so many respects. It uses software rendering, for one, completely ignoring even basic hardware acceleration. Plus, stemming from its cross-platform approach, it is particularly poor with respect to user input. A more appropriate platform would be Direct2D/Direct3D/DirectInput, for rendering and input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MFC is a C++ framework that encapsulates the core elements of the Windows API. It's *primarily* intended for creating standard, windowed applications that the user interacts with on the desktop.

It comes with a built-in graphics framework: GDI. The one that was introduced with Windows, revolutionary for its time because it abstracted away hardware-specific details and allowed programmers to write general code that ran on any machine Windows ran on. But it was never particularly good for games; it was designed for Windows-style business applications. It was awesome for text (and is still arguably the best option that there is—have you looked at how Direct2D renders text lately?), and handled simple graphics, but consider that before alternative graphics-specialized frameworks like OpenGL were available, most game developers stuck with DOS, where they could/were forced to interact directly with the graphics hardware at a low level.

So if you *want* to use MFC and OpenGL together, you *can*, but I don't really see the point. The only real benefit you'd be gaining from MFC is a reduction of 100-some-odd lines of code that sets up the fundamental skeleton of any Windows application. For example, [considering this sample OpenGL program](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd369065.aspx), using MFC would essentially allow the `WinMain` and the `MainWndProc` functions to be buried deep in the bowels of the MFC framework code, rather than appearing directly in your code. But, like I said, big deal. The *majority* of your code is going to be OpenGL-specific, and MFC won't help there.

The only way it might make sense for the two to interact is if you wrote the launchpad/host for the game using MFC and GDI (i.e., the part that displays windows and dialogs on screen), and then the game portion itself in OpenGL (launched once you clicked a "Start" button on the dialog interface).

And of course, even if you wanted to do this, MFC is not your only option. There are tons of C++ frameworks for writing Windows applications. Everyone has their favorite. Despite what some may tell you, there's nothing *wrong* with MFC if you already know it and/or are comfortable with the Windows API. But don't waste time *learning* it. Use [WTL](http://wtl.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Comment: I like your explanation, just one more question: If I were to develop a window business style application in C++ (let's say it's my favorite language) is MFC "old technology" and there is a new way?  I know about WPF but that's for .NET (c#, vb, etc) as I know

Comment: @Christopher Pretty much, yeah. You can write WPF apps in a special C++ with .NET extensions, but it isn't sensible and you lose any real benefit of writing in C++. Might as well just learn C#, it isn't that difficult. So unless you already know MFC well (in which case, use it), you should pick a different UI framework for C++ development. Something like WTL or Qt (but [I do not like Qt](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/88689), despite its popularity).

Comment: +1 for providing a solid rationale why MFC may not be the best option in this particular case, without the *"MFC is ancient"* mantra. I'd +10 this if I could for not suggesting Qt. Besides WTL, [Win32++](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32-framework/) looks like a nice library as well. This is probably what MFC would have looked like had it been implemented 20 years after its inception. And doesn't require ATL like WTL.

Answer (score 1):

You would NOT use MFC simply because it is meant for general application development giving you features and classes that you will most likely never use!

A good start would be to look at SFML http://www.sfml-dev.org/ or (my personal favourite) SDL http://www.libsdl.org/. These libraries were written to develop games or at least multimedia applications using them.

Writing a Game Editor in MFC can be a good idea though!

Comment: Another Question: Why use Windows anyway? Or why stick to Windows?! The frameworks I named in my answer are both PLATFORM INDEPENDENT - I think that is something we all are also looking for :).

Comment: Platform independence is not a quality in and of itself. It's something you aim for when you have a striking reason to do so. It's nothing *we all* are looking for. Particularly with games, *Windows-only* is a valid restriction.

Comment: @IInspectable +1 because that's exactly the reason